# Calling parent window method from Iframe (different)

Tags: javascript, iframe, same-origin-policy

I have a page on a domain:

http://main.mydomain.com/frame.cfm which holds an iframe,
loading a domain http://www.anotherdomain.com.

This page http://www.anotherdomain.com has a script reference to http://sub.mydomain.com/somescript.js

This somescript is a tracking script like google Analytics, which loads with each request of www.anotherdomain.com.

At a certain stage, the script http://sub.mydomain.com/somescript.js in the page www.anotherdomain.com will try to call `window.top.aFunction(); or parent.aFunction();`

to make the parent window do something.

I know about the X-Frame-Options and the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header and tried both, but still when I browse in my iframe on www.anotherdomain.com I get a error message in Firebug telling me:

```
Error: Permission denied to access property 'relocate'window.top.aFunction();
```

In my web.config on the main.domain site i have the following rules:

```
<httpProtocol>
     <customHeaders>
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="http://sub.mydomain.com" />
        <add name="X-Frame-Options" value="ALLOW-FROM http://sub.mydomain.com" />
     </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
```

Which in my opinion should grant the sub.mydomain.com access to the script on main.mydomain.com.

I am testing this with all the domains except the www.anotherdomain.com locally on my pc with host reference in place.

Any idea what I am missing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't access the parent window function's methods through a cross domain iFrame. It goes against the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) . The `X-Frame` http header response tells the browser whether it is allowed to render a page in the iFrame and does not help your situation.

The solution I recommend is to use `window.postMessage()` to communicate between the two frames. Look at http://ejohn.org/blog/cross-window-messaging/

Comment: hmmm, okay. Looks a bit like a work around, does it? Internet Explorer doesn't seem to support it, yet. And I do need to suppoer IE7+. Concerning the same origin policy: I find it annoying that my script page and frame page are on the same main domain. That should give enough security in my opinion? I could put the script also on the main.mydomain.com domain, but I have a framework running there that will catch my seperate script request and will require some codeing to ignore this script in framework context. Not very elegant

Comment: Thank you! I also noticed that I am allowed to set the parent.location to something else by the script in the iframe. Calling a function in the parent doing the same as setting it directly is appearantly different, security wise. Bit weird. Also, it would be nice if they are less strict if they don;'t look at at subdomains but at domain. Should be safe enough in my current perspective.