# how to call javascript function on Parent page from inside an iframe page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I want to call a javascript function of parent page where iframe is placed.
from the page inside an iframe.

i  have tried 
`parent.function_in_parent();` 
its not working

yes both are in same domain.

for example: 
there are 5 .net pages page1.aspx,page2.aspx,page3.aspx,page4.aspx,page5.aspx and master.aspx

master.aspx contains the iframe with source page1.aspx, i want to call function abc() written in master.aspx from page1.aspx

Comment: please post your code. before asking question, do some home work and give as much good information on the problem. so that everbody can understand it.

Comment: is the iframe source from the same domain or different one

Comment: There is also `Same Origin Policy` to consider http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9700766/iframe-call-parent-function

Comment: If short, if both the parent and child are from same origin then it should be possible, else `Same Origin Policy` will prevent it

Answer (score 1):

In short, if both the parent and child are from same origin then [it should be possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2161388/iframe-function-calling-from-iframe-to-parent-page-javascript-function), else `Same Origin Policy` [will prevent it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13313052/calling-parent-window-method-from-iframe-different)

Answer (score 0):

Check this

[Calling a parent window function from an iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2161388/iframe-function-calling-from-iframe-to-parent-page-javascript-function)

If your iframe has the different domain to the parent, your work will be a lot more harder. You'll need to see [easyXDM](http://easyxdm.net/wp/)